# How to automate github branch deployment using Jenkins

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

In my org, currently we are deploying the branches manually.

the steps are

1. tsh login "my auth details"
2. tsh ssh myusername@server
3. sudo su
4. run_command

this gives me a list of options like, branch , env etc. then the deployments starts. I was told this can be automated using jenkins. But I am not sure how and where to start.

Can anybody help in pointing out the resources from where I can learn about this and implement ?

Comment: You can check git hook, I think it will help

Comment: Sounds like Ansible could be helpful. You can execute Ansible playbook in a Jenkins job.